# Radon and moisture mitigation when joists are on dirt

Tags: crawlspace, vapor-barrier, radon

In this house in a dry climate, the floor joists are directly on dirt, and the floor boards are just one layer (no subfloor). After 150 years, there is no rot, and there has of course been substantial air exchange with the cavities under the floor. There is no venting to the exterior, as the walls are 3 feet thick.

I'm going to build up the floor with foam board panels and another floor, to provide insulation and leveling. My concern is that this will seal of the cavities which will increase moisture under there, and maybe increase radon. It seems impractical to try to vent each of the little spaces.

One idea I had is to put a pipe across the current floor, perpendicular to the joists, and drill holes into each of the cavities, and put a T in the pipe for each hole, so all of them are connected. Then use a radon fan to keep a vacuum in the cavities. This should reduce radon and prevent moisture and rot. The new floor would go over this pipe since I have 2.5 inches to build up. However, I've never heard of or seen anything like this, so maybe I'm crazy? What do you think?

Comment: What is the radon level in the house now? If you don't know, you should test before anything. If you know you have a problem level now, have you considered that radon may be coming from your 3 ft thick walls and not the ground? Clear knowledge of your walls' construction and the source of their mineral components would be helpful. A heat recovery fresh air exchange could help mitigate radon from thick walls containing unusual levels of uranium found in New Mexico. See https://nmgs.nmt.edu/publications/guidebooks/downloads/71/71_p0195_p0202.pdf

Comment: It's impossible to test right now because the house is missing windows so we would be testing outside air. I will test after the windows are in - 3-4 months from now. It's really helpful to know that the walls could be a source, although the material is from 1860, before any significant uranium mining was done.

Comment: Before any uranium mining . . . but from a site that later *was* mined from uranium? It's possible. Prospectors walked around with a geiger counter all over NM because uranium deposits come all the way up to the surface in places. Someone with a geiger counter could tell you immediately if your walls are a low-level radiation source, usually non-hazardous unless they emit radon into an enclosed space. Check with NM Enviro Dept, your county, or take to social media to find a local rockhound with a geiger counter, who will almost certainly check your walls for free.